# Count all cells after the first non zero value found - Excel?

Tags: excel, count

I have this example:

I need a formula to count all the numbers after the first aparition of a non zero value.

The Values range is A1:H4. But i need count for every line A1:H1; A2:H2...A4:H4.

0 0 7 2 0 0 0 9 - result of numbers counted 6
5 0 4 0 2 0 0 0 - result of numbers counted 8
0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 - result of numbers counted 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 - result of numbers counted 1

Thank you!
c

Comment: How your data is organized? Are the rows in the same cells (separated by a space)? Are there in separate cells?

Comment: Are those values in separate cells, or is e.g. "00120001" in a single cell?

Comment: Sorry, values are in range A1:H1 in this example....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are in A1:H1, **array formula****:

`=COUNT(H1:INDEX(1:1,MATCH("",T(1/A1:H1),0)))`

To take an example: with A1:H1 containing:

0 0 7 2 0 0 0 9

the reciprocation:

`1/A1:H1`

will return:

`{#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,0.142857142857143,0.5,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,0.111111111111111}`

Applying the T function to this array returns:

`{#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,"","",#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,""}`

i.e. all non-zeroes in the original range have now been reduced to the null string ""; all zeroes to an error.

We can now perform an exact match for the null string, such that:

`MATCH("",T(1/A1:H1),0)`

which is:

`MATCH("",{#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,"","",#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,""},0)`

gives:

`3`

And so:

`INDEX(1:1,MATCH("",T(1/A1:H1),0))`

which is:

`INDEX(1:1,3)`

returns a range reference to the cell:

`C1`

and so, finally:

`COUNT(H1:INDEX(1:1,MATCH("",T(1/A1:H1),0)))`

which is:

`COUNT(H1:C1)`

in which Excel will correct the range reference to:

`COUNT(C1:H1)`

is:

`6`

as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
=LEN(RIGHT(A1,FIND("1",A1&"1")))
```